# Find a parametrization of the intersection curve between surfaces

Tags: plane-curves, parametric

> Find a parametrization of the intersection curve between the surfaces $−3x^2+2z=10$ and $4x^2+10y^2=5$. You should parametrize such that $y=k\sin(t)$ for some constant k.

The answer should be in vector form.

I'm a bit unsure about how to attack this question. Some step by step help would be nice but some hints or answer is okay too.

Comment: I assume that `x2` and `y2` were intended to be $x^2$ and $y^2$, right? [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first surface is a parabolic cylinder, while the second is an elliptic cylinder. A parameterisation of the second one is $x(u,t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\cos t, y(u,t)=\sqrt{2}\sin t, z(u,t)=u$. Now replace these values in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The second equation is an ellipse which might be parametrized as $\bigl(\sqrt{2.5}\cos(t),\sqrt{0.5}\sin(t)\bigr)$.